# Magento 2 : Display tier price for 1 quantity

Tags: magento2, tierprice, tiered-pricing

I want to tier price with 1 quantity also.

I added it in Magento Admin Panel but it is not displayed.

Please check the image so you have batter idea.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much price you added in 1 qty?.

Comment: @MonarkBhawani no price I am adding in I just want price of product there.

Comment: I mean, how much price you add in admin panel tier price for 1 qty?

Comment: I want to display statically so I overwrite the tierprice file and put <li> there for that.
I got the all value but exclusive tax value could not formatted due to I got it as object.

Comment: please add your code in your question. So I have checked your code and tell you something.

Comment: @MonarkBhawani which code you want sir?

Comment: you override the file. You can change any code in that file?.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting that you have added tier price correctly.

Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and flush the cache